# Using your own static library in your own Qt application

Tags: c++, qt

Following the [How to create a library with Qt and use it in an application](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application), I was able to create and use my own shared library in my own Qt app.

Going forward in the tutorial I reached the [Creating a static library](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application#Creating_a_static_library) part which I might (or not) succeeded to understand. I was able to build `libtest.a` but when trying to use it I got:

```
15:35:25: Running steps for project loadTestLib...
15:35:25: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\User\Downloads\library\client\static\loadTestLib.pro -r -spec win32-g++
15:35:27: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
15:35:27: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/library/client/static'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I. -I.. -I..\testlib -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore -Irelease -IC:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o release\main.o ..\main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release\client.exe release/main.o  -lmingw32 -LC:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw492_32/lib -lqtmain -lshell32 -L../testlib/static/release -ltest -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core 
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6WidgetC1Ev'
Makefile.Release:77: recipe for target 'release\client.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Downloads/library/client/static'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV6Widget'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV6Widget'
C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: release/main.o: bad reloc address 0x13 in section `.eh_frame'
C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\client.exe] Error 1
makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
15:35:32: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project loadTestLib (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
15:35:32: Elapsed time: 00:06.
```

Here is the code of the library:

test.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = debug
} else {
    DESTDIR = release
}

OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR

DEPENDPATH += . ..

INCLUDEPATH += . ..

SOURCES += ../test.cpp

HEADERS += ../test.h

DEFINES += TEST
```

test.h

```
#include <QtGui>

#if defined TEST
#define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#include <QWidget>

class TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget();
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "test.h"

Widget::Widget() : QWidget() {}
```

And here is the code for the client app:

loadTestLib.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = client

TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = debug
} else {
    DESTDIR = release
}

OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR

SOURCES += ../main.cpp

DEPENDPATH += . ../testlib

INCLUDEPATH += . .. ../testlib

LIBS += -L../testlib/static/release -ltest
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "testlib/test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.resize(200,200);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Please remove "TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT" and "TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT". That will work fine for you.

Comment: That solved the issue. Is there any way to keep the same .h for both shared and static builds?

Comment: Yes Please, Keep it same.

Comment: Well, it seems that stuff isn't needed. I'll appreciate if you comment why it is so, in opposite to what is mentioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already said in the comments to your questions the macros needed in dynamic linking caused trouble in static linking because they shouldn't be defined when linking statically.

It depends on your environment and/or compiler if the macros are defined to something or empty in `qcompilerdetection.h`.

E.g. in Windows environment they are defined like this:

```
#define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define Q_DECL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
```

If you want to **keep your code compatible with multiple environments** then you can do like this:

In your header file:

```
#ifndef TEST_STATIC
#if defined TEST
#define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
#else
#define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC
#endif


class TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Widget : public QWidget
{
};
```

static dll pro and pro of app linking with static dll:

```
DEFINES += TEST_STATIC
```

- TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC expands to empty

dynamic dll pro:

```
DEFINES += TEST
```

- TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC expands to Q_DECL_EXPORT

app linking with dynamic dll:

- TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC expands to Q_DECL_IMPORT